# Run EF migrations on Startup in asp.net core 6 application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

How can I run ef migrations on startup in asp.net 6 application.

This is my Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 23));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(x => x.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .EnableDetailedErrors());
```

How can I execute MyContext.Database.Migrate() here?

Comment: Bear in mind that you may not want to run migrations every time, for example, if your code is run on a multi-instance basis (for load sharing etc), as multiple instances will try to update the database at the same time.

Comment: @Neil I understand, I am running only on a single vps for now

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try below:

```
var app = builder.Build();

// omitted

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();    
    context.Database.Migrate();
}

// omitted

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 9):

Just add following lines in Program.cs

```
await using var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope();
await using var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DataContext>();
await db.Database.MigrateAsync();
```